# Flutter test fails with machine flag but successful without it

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project and ~1500 widget tests in the /test directory.
After some changes, which don't contain braking changes IMO ~70 tests become fails on CI.

The weirdest part for me is that all tests are successful when I run it locally by command

```
flutter test test
```

But when I run them with command

```
flutter test --machine test
```

some tests failed, as well as on CI.

I tried to select only failed tests and run it but it works successfully.

Any ideas on how to debug it and figure out why it fails?